# SVN rebase branch from trunk

Tags: svn, patch, trunk

Hallo all.
I have a java project using SVN as scm.
I have the trunk line where I have the PRODUCTION_LINE and some branches for the next releases.

When I found a bug in production I fix it on trunk and release the software.
I would like to take the fix also on the branches without closing them.
Is it possibile?

Kind regards
Massimo

Comment: what do you mean by "closing a branch" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need the fix in your development branches, just merge the fix using:

svn merge -rXXX:YYY <path_to_trunk>

where XXX is revision prior to fixes and YYY is the last of the fix commits.

Usually you should not need this because development branches contain changes that are going to be merged back into trunk which already has the fix.

Comment: Yes that's right. But since I have to deploy the software in 3 environments (e.g. application test, system test, certification) before production, every of them would have those bugs.

Comment: Then use merge command as I suggested, execute this in the branch directory. Honestly I have never deployed anything but trunk or release branch to test/preproduction/production environments. Maybe you should merge to trunk more eagerly and maintain release branches for previous versions? For example we have 1.3 developed in trunk while customers use versions 1.1 and 1.2 in their respective branches. When first customer migrates to 1.3, we will slow down development until 1.3 goes into separate branch and trunk goes 1.4. We seldom use development branches, they are always pain to merge.

Comment: If I rebase a branch this way, will I still be able to easily merge the branch specific changes back to trunk without conflicts?

Comment: There could be conflicts requiring manual resolution. That's why I suggested another approach in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer : I am the author of the solution.
https://github.com/qbolec/svn_rebase